# Reset Find and Replace dialogs to Current Document in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to force the Find and Replace dialog boxes, in visual studio, to auto select **Current Document** in the Look in drop down? It should do this only on reopening the dialog. I regularly forget to switch back from entire solution or project and end up wasting a lot of time waiting for VS to search everything including designer files! I'm hoping for a registry hack or something.

I'm sure this is a major annoyance for others too. Any tips on this would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: +1 on the question.  I HATE this 'feature' where it remembers the last setting. The answer below doesn't work for me though because I don't want results coming up in the find list, I want to be taken to each result with the search term highlighted.

Comment: Same here.  This is one more annoying "feature" that should have been killed in its infancy, just like drag-drop should be killed in the Solution Explorer.I never, ever, ever, EVER want to search ANYTHING except the current document.  I really don't care where Visual Studio thinks the focus is, and I don't care what I searched the last time.  When I press Ctrl-F I want it to *always* search the current document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio retains separate settings for dialogs shown using `Ctrl+F` and `Ctrl+Shift+F` shortcuts, though dialogs themselves are identical. So when I want to search in current document, I hit `Ctrl+F`. When I want to search in Project/Solution/directory, I hit `Ctrl+Shift+F` and then choose where I want to search.

Comment: +1 This is the best solution so far thank you. I will likely accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can use the Find combo box to only search the current document. The shortcut is `Ctrl+/` or maybe `Ctrl+D`. It moves the focus to the Find combo box and you can type and press Enter to search.

Comment: ctrl+/ does not seem to do anything for me. I tried it while in the editor. Where is this find combo?

Comment: @Tim - Maybe you customized your toolbar :-) Should be on the Standard toolbar to the right of the Continue (F5) button and Solution Configurations combo box. In this [image](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2009/02/20/a-new-look-for-visual-studio-2010.aspx), it's the third combo box from the left.

Comment: @Tim - Based on [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/06/16/using-the-go-to-find-combo-box-vstipfind0009.aspx) it may be `Ctrl+D` depending on how you configured VS.