# Find in current document only - Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, search, find, visual-studio-2013

I'd like to search **the current document only** using a **single command**
(e.g. defined as Alt-F)

1. Selecting "Current Document" using the mouse is no option, it gets really annoying.
2. Incremental Find (Crtl-I) is a nice feature, it seems to do exactly what I want, BUT it does not auto-fill the search using the current word/selection! I almost always want to find a word under the cursor

Does anyone know a workaround. Maybe a macro for setting "Current Document", or a mod to Incremental Find.

Comment: You can check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111183/reset-find-and-replace-dialogs-to-current-document-in-visual-studio), the question is similar to yours.

Comment: I know that post, no real answer there...